# How do I claim bitcoin from an old wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info

at my Blockchain "Bitcoin Address" page, it shows "Unspent Outputs":
Summary:
Address, Hash 160, Tools and 
Transactions:
No. Transactions, Total Received and Final Balance. (I HAVE 0.4 FINAL BALANCE OF BITCOIN).

Then a REQUEST PAYMENT button.

I have some Bitcoins (0.4) in the Final Balance of "Unspent Outputs".
I used this back in 2016.
Today, 9th November, 2017 i opened a Blockchain Wallet for the first time.
It says i have a $0 balance.

My question is, how do i transfer this balance (0.4) to my Blockchain Wallet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

regards
Kel.

Comment: blockchain.info can show the sum of unspent outpots incorrect. can you publish your address? can you check that all other block explorers either show the same 0.4 as unspent on this address?

Comment: I`ll look for the address.

Answer (score 1):

From your earlier (now deleted) comment, I think this is your address: https://blockchain.info/address/176T2BxKAraEnusvuuK48RPA5yVYQRhMdc.

You need access to the original wallet with which you received the bitcoin. Which wallet did you use back in 2015 and 2016? Can you still access it? The "Request Payment" button is for sending more bitcoins to that address, not for spending the coins that are already there.

Comment: Seems like this is done and over.

https://longhorn.bullpay.com/?gateway=2&data=176T2BxKAraEnusvuuK48RPA5yVYQRhMdc

On 11/10/17, 1 day after the question/answer was posted, a transaction of .4247.. BTC was moved out of the wallet. Since the amount is similar, the timing is really similar, and Adam's answer contained the address referencing a deleted comment it seems like the question was resolved.